# Just finished CS50's "Caesar" - How can I make it better?

Tags: c, caesar-cipher

How can I improve this code? I wanted to have a separate method for "isdigit" but when I tried making it, I kept getting the error: "non-void function does not return a value in all control paths [-Werror,-Wreturn-type] }"

I also don't fully understand how I pulled of this part, the more I look at it the less it makes sense:

```
if (isupper(c))
        {
            c = c - 65 + k;
            c = c % 26 + 65;
        }
```

Here's the full code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


char rotate(char s, int k);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // check if they input a string
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        //checks if each char is a digit
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++)

            if(isdigit(argv[1][i]) == false)
            {
                 printf("Usage: ./caesar key");
                return 1;
             }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key");
        return 1;
    }



    //convert to int
    int key_int = atoi(argv[1]);


    //get plaintext
    string plaintext = get_string("enter message: ");

    //encrypt
    printf("ciphertext: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(plaintext); i++)
    {
        rotate(plaintext[i], key_int);
    }
    printf("\n");


}


//rotates a char by the amount given in the key
char rotate(char c, int k)
{
    // checks if its a letter
    if (isalpha(c))
    {
        // if it's uppercase
        if (isupper(c))
        {
            c = c - 65 + k;
            c = c % 26 + 65;
        }
        // if its lowercase
        else
        {
            c = c - 97 + k;
            c = c % 26 + 97;

        }
        printf("%c", c);
    }
    // not alphabetical characters don't get changed (1,?,.):
    else
    {
        printf("%c", c);
    }
    return c;
}
```

I did get 11/11 so I guess it worked though lol

Answer (score 3):

## Character coding concerns

It looks like you have assumed that input is ASCII.  If that's specified in the problem statement, then that's okay, but if not, you'll run into a couple of problems on non-ASCII platforms:

1. Plain `char` can be signed, and the `<ctype.h>` functions require *positive* integer inputs (or `EOF`, but that's inapplicable here).  We need to convert characters to `unsigned char` before they are promoted to `int`.
2. Some character codings don't have contiguous alphabetic characters like that.  Binary-coded decimal codings have gaps every ten letters.  The most prominent is EBCDIC, and the range `'a'` to `'z'` in that coding is `abcdefghi«»ðýþ±°jklmnopqrªºæ¸Æ¤µ~stuvwxyz`, so the simple arithmetic operation doesn't work there, even if you replace `65` with `'A'` and `97` with `'a'`.

---

## Errors to wrong stream

Error messages should go to the standard *error* stream, not to standard output, and should end with a newline.  And we have a macro that better documents an error status from `main()`:

```
            fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s key\n", argv[0]);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
```

---

## Don't calculate `strlen()` every iteration

This loop is inefficient:

> ```
>     for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++)
> ```

Either store the result of `strlen()` before the loop, or avoid the need for it by looping until you hit the null character that terminates the loop.  The same applies to the loop over the contents of `plaintext`.

Or, instead of separately validating the argument and later parsing with `atoi()`, use a more capable conversion function that can report a parse failure - I recommend `strtol()`:

```
    char *endpos;
    long key = strtol(argv[1], &endpos, 10);
    if (*endpos || endpos == argv[1]) {
        /* Empty string, or non-numeric characters */
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: key '%s' is not a number\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

---

## Don't mix computation and I/O

The `rotate()` function outputs as well as returning the modified character.  Program design is easier to follow if we don't mix output with computation - just return `c` and have the caller print it (`putc()` is simpler than `printf("%c")`, so consider that as a better choice).